# Manual slotAssignment doesn't assign contents

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

```js
class RealTodo extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open", slotAssignment: "manual" });
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        const todoTemplate = document.getElementById("todo_template");
        const todoApp = todoTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(todoApp);

        const slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot");
        console.log(slot);

        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = "Buy food";
        slot.assign(li);
    }
}
customElements.define("real-todo", RealTodo);
```

```html
    <template id="todo_template">
    <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
        <ol>
            <slot></slot>
        </ol>
    </template>
  
  <real-todo></real-todo>
```

I try to assign content inside shadowDom's slot manually.
It doesn't assign. No error show.
I tested in firefox, chrome.

According to spec `slot.assign(nodes);` will assign inside `slotAssignment: "manual"` shadowdom

Comment: `slot.append(li);` works but not finding good documentation around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `const li = document.createElement("li");` creates a Node **in memory**

`SLOTElement.assign()` only accepts **existing DOM Element(s)** *in
**first level** lightDOM*

And you don't want to use `append[Child]()`, because that **moves** a DOM Element

```js
customElements.define("real-todo", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    const button = (props) => Object.assign(document.createElement("button"),props);
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: "open", slotAssignment: "manual" })
      .append(
        button({ innerHTML:"Food"   , onclick : e => this.showlist("food")   }),
        button({ innerHTML:"Animals", onclick : e => this.showlist("animal") }),
        document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true)
      );
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.showlist();
  }
  showlist( list=this.getAttribute("list") ){
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("span").innerHTML = list;
    const li = this.querySelectorAll(`li[list*="${list}"]`);
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot").assign(...li);
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="REAL-TODO">
    <h1>A <span></span> list</h1>
    <ol>
        <slot></slot>
    </ol>
</template>

<real-todo list="animal">
  <li list="animal">Cat</li>
  <li list="animal">Dog</li>
  <li list="food">Pie</li>
  <li list="food">Beer</li>
  <li list="food">Pizza</li>
  <li list="animal,food">Chicken</li>
  <div>
    <li list="animal,food">Never listed!!</li>
  </div>
</real-todo>
```

#### The inspector will show which `LI` elements are slotted:

[image]

Comment: Check your answer in console. LI element is outside of shodow dom,which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Even if i append `const li = document.createElement("li");` inside documnet.body before assign. It doesn't assign inside slot.

Comment: the ``LI`` **must be** in lightDOM

Comment: You attach shadow with `slotAssignment: "manual"` but assign slot with `named` assignment which doesn't allow. According to spec: **you cannot mix declarative and imperative slot assignment**

Comment: ⚠️ Read the code carefully, and execute it, there are **no named slots**; as you say _You cannot mix declarative and imperative slot assignment_

Comment: Oh !! Now, i understand, Only lightDOM nodes able to assigned by `slot.assign()`;